# Solidity syntax Error: Expected primary expression

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm trying to make a function that includes a for loop and an if/if else statement and am running into errors. The syntax regarding where to put the brackets here confuses me.

```
function decider(nbaTeam[] memory team) public {
    for(uint i=0; i < 31; i++) {
    if (team[i].oRtg > avgOrtg && team[i].dRtg < avgDrtg) {
        niceTeams.push(team);
    }
    }   else if (team[i].oRtg <= avgOrtg && team[i].dRtg >= avgDrtg) {
        naughtyTeams.push(team);
    }
    }
```

"Expected primary expression." error on the else if statement line.

Comment: It would have been better if you can share a full code for proper understanding but you can just declare a return statement in your 'else' block code and omit the expression

Comment: ok I will do that next time, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you indent the code properly you'll see that there's an extra `}` before the `else if`. In solidity braces are used to surround block of codes `{}`.

```
function decider(nbaTeam[] memory team) public {
    for (uint i=0; i < 31; i++) {
        if (team[i].oRtg > avgOrtg && team[i].dRtg < avgDrtg) {
            niceTeams.push(team);    
        } else if (team[i].oRtg <= avgOrtg && team[i].dRtg >= avgDrtg) {
            naughtyTeams.push(team);
        }
    }
}
```